# Vue.js Error "Cannot find module './undefined'" from webpack when using src=require()

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am trying to load images from a local folder using the src="" from the img tag but I want to load them using the backend. The frontend already has the relative path which is "../assets/imgs/" the backend just has the name and extension ex) "1.png". Thing is that it does work but I'm getting error messages.

This is causing me an issue

```
<img width=100px height=100px :src="getIconPath(`${user.icon}`)"/>
```

here is the function that gets called

```
  methods: {
    getIconPath(iconName) {
      return iconName ? require("../assets/imgs/" + iconName) : ''
    }
```

Here are both the error messages I am getting on the console

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './undefined'"
found in
---> <Profile> at src/components/profile.vue
       <Navbar> at src/components/navbar.vue
         <Main> at src/main.vue
           <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
Error: "Cannot find module './undefined'"
    webpackContextResolve .*$:13
    webpackContext .*$:8
    getIconPath profile.vue:74
    render profile.vue:12
    VueJS 43
    <anonymous> main.js:31
    js app.js:1415
    __webpack_require__ app.js:785
    fn app.js:151
    1 app.js:1488
    __webpack_require__ app.js:785
    checkDeferredModules app.js:46
    <anonymous> app.js:861
    <anonymous>
```

I found very little resources to help out but many of them have said that required fixes their issues. So far I tried moving it to a different folder, moving the require as a function method, using absolute path, using v-attr, and binding it without require. Still I haven't had any luck getting rid of the error message. Here is another link of someone else having the same issue as me but I still couldn't figure out how they fixed it.

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-fix-the-console-log-error-when-using-require-method-to-bind-an-img-src/77979

I would very much appreciate the help!! I've been stuck for many hours on this and I can't seem to find a helpful solution. If this isn't a good way to go about loading images from the backend feel free to suggest any other alternative ways to do so. Thank You!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61493854/edit) instead of putting code in the comments section. Please also provide all relevant information such as where the `user` (or is it `image`) data comes from and what its data format looks like

Comment: noted thank you sorry this is my first time! I edited my post hope that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Where does `user` come from? Is it loaded asynchronously? If so, what does its initial data look like (before it's _loaded_)?

Comment: user comes from my store. I named it that way. Honestly I have no clue if it is loaded asynchronously. I am using axios to connect to my api not sure if that's useful to know. Actually I changed it to `getIconPath(user.icon)` as you mentioned and it is loading without any error messages!

Comment: I'd just written that up as an answer below 

Comment: Could you console.log(iconName) after  this line `getIconPath(iconName) {`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess here and say that `user` is populated with data asynchronously. I bet you have something like this in your initial data or store

```js
{
  user: {}
}
```

The issue here is that `user.icon` is `undefined`, at least for some period of time. Where you are needlessly converting that into a string with

```js
getIconPath(`${user.icon}`)
```

will convert `undefined` into the string `"undefined"` (because JavaScript is fun like that), hence your error message. The simple solution is to **not** use a string template, ie

```js
getIconPath(user.icon)
```

---

To avoid these sorts of problems, I would instead use a computed property to resolve image imports. This is more efficient than executing a method in your template which happens on every *tick*

```js
computed: {
  userWithIcon () {
    return {
      ...this.user, 
      icon: this.user.icon && require(`../assets/imgs/${this.user.icon}`)
    }
  }
}
```

and in your template

```html
<img width="100px" height="100px" :src="userWithIcon.icon">
```

Comment: AH THIS MAKES SO MUCH SENSE NOW!!! THANK YOU!!! VERY MUCH!!! Is there any way to add to your reputation or something? I appreciate it! :D

Comment: @VictorDanielCampa you're welcome and by accepting my answer, you've already given me those delicious reputation points 

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and I was able to solve it by making sure that my data was ready before rendering the view. using @Phil assumption that you have something like `user: {}` in your data, you can just wrap your whole HTML in `<div v-if="user !== null"></div>`. This makes sure that the user data is ready before even trying to render any image at all or use any data from the user object.

This should eliminate any error at all.