# Dynamic images failing at production build VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to load dynamic images here. My api provides me only with the filename. I combine it with the path (which is the public path of nodejs), then I require it from vuejs to show the image.

It all works fine in the development but when it comes to production build it fails and says "Cannot find the module".

I've spent tons of hours to this and still cannot find an answer.

Edit - I noticed after the production build earlier images I saved from development mode is also displayed in production build.but If I try save a new image from a production build it wouldnt work.My URL is somehow converted to point the public/img folder in vue from development mode.

in HTML

```html
      <div class="section-1" v-for="(cardinfo,index) in cardinfos" style="cursor:pointer" :key="index" @mouseover="moment(cardinfo)">
        <div class="img-wrap" >
          <a @click="deleteAd(cardinfo)">
            <mdb-icon v-if="data.myads" icon="trash-alt" class="close red-text" size="lg" />
          </a>
          <img class="img-fluid ad-image" :src="getImgUrl(cardinfo.images[0])" alt="ad" v-on:click="navigateToAd(cardinfo)" />
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper" v-on:click="navigateToAd(cardinfo)">
          <mdb-card-title>{{cardinfo.subject}}</mdb-card-title>
          <hr class="mb-3" />
          <div class="venue">
            <strong>Venue:</strong>
            <p>{{cardinfo.venue}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="contact">
            <strong>Contact:</strong>
            <p>{{cardinfo.contact}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="Conducted-By" >
            <p title="Click to visit">{{cardinfo.lecturer}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-footer">
          <div class="info">
            <div class="name">{{time}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

in Script

```
getImgUrl(pic) {
  return require("../../../tuition/public/images/" + pic);
}
```

Error

````
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 Error: Cannot find module './marques-brownlee-wallpaper.jpg-1588649676704.png'
    at n (.*$:142)
    at s (.*$:137)
    at o.getImgUrl (Card.vue:107)
    at Card.vue?852f:1
    at o.jt [as _l] (vue.runtime.esm.js:2630)
    at o.B (Card.vue?852f:1)
    at o.e._render (vue.runtime.esm.js:3548)
    at o.a (vue.runtime.esm.js:4066)
    at na.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:4479)
    at na.run (vue.runtime.esm.js:4554)```
````

Comment: What is `cardinfo.images`? What data is assigned to it and more importantly, **when**?

Comment: @Phil cardinfo.images is an array of filenames stored in public folder of my nodejs api.api stores the image there and sends the unique file name to the database.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions at all. Somewhere, you are assigning a value to `cardinfo` and / or `cardinfo.images`. Please show that code by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61605603/edit)

Comment: Also, what **exactly** is the error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js Error "Cannot find module './undefined'" from webpack when using src=require()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61493854/vue-js-error-cannot-find-module-undefined-from-webpack-when-using-src-requ)

Comment: @Phil edited the question

Comment: looks like your api is remote and images are local, while it's possible to get it working it's not a very good setup. You may want to static-host the images with the api, then you can reference the images as remote.

Comment: @Daniel I saved images in the static folder of node which is public directory.are you suggesting cloud host images?

Comment: Please note that this works perfectly fine in development.after I create a dist this happens.

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to cloud host them. You already have an api service, they could be hosted with that service. It's a better way to go, because (I assume) the API has information on the images. It works on your dev instance, because when you're using the dev server, it runs as a server, so if can host files for you, but when you've compiled it and use a different server to host the "dist", your static files are no longer available.