# Data rendered on the screen but has error on the console (Firebase with Vue): Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'contents' of null

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I'm trying to get **lesson.contents** to render on the screen but I have some errors on the console. Here is the code (I'm using Firebase with Vue 3)

```
<template>
  <AddContent :lesson="lesson" />
  <div v-if="lesson.contents.length"> 
    <h2>{{ lesson.contents }}</h2>
  </div>
  
</template>
 
<script>
import ContentList from "@/components/ContentList.vue";
import AddContent from "@/components/AddContent.vue";
import getDocument from "@/composables/getDocument";
import { ref } from "vue";
 
export default {
  props: ["id"],
  components: { AddContent },
  setup(props) {
    const { document: lesson } = getDocument("lessons", props.id);
 
    return { lesson };
  },
};
</script>
 
<style>
</style>
```

Then I have this error:

[image: error]

What I'm confused is that I'm still able to render **lesson.contents** on the screen:
[image]

I've been trying a few hours trying to fix it but I could not find out why. I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you!

My `getDocument.js` code:

```
import { watchEffect, ref } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'

const getDocument = (collection, id) => {

  let document = ref(null)
  let error = ref(null)

  // register the firestore collection reference
  let documentRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)

  const unsub = documentRef.onSnapshot(doc => {
    // need to make sure the doc exists & has data
    if(doc.data()) {
      document.value = {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
      error.value = null
    }
    else {
      error.value = 'that document does not exist'
    }
  }, err => {
    console.log(err.message)
    error.value = 'problem fetching the document'
  })

  watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
    onInvalidate(() => unsub())
  });

  return { error, document }

}

export default getDocument
```

Comment: Looks like `getDocument()` should return an initial object with `contents` set to an empty array. Right now, it looks like it does not have a `contents` property initially

Comment: Thank you. What would you advise me to do to fix it? I checked the props using Vue debugger and it shows the data of the `contents` property. You could check the screenshot here: https://www.screencast.com/t/z7TQt1pM

Comment: Please include the `getDocument` implementation in your question.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61494074/283366) might help illustrate what I mean by _"initial data"_

Comment: I just added my code for `getDocument.js`. Could you help taking a look to see what I can do Phil? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line...

```js
let document = ref(null)
```

initialises `document` to `null`. It is only after the `onSnapshot` callback is executed does it receive a value with the `contents` property.

To keep your application from throwing...

> Cannot read property 'contents' of null

you can initialise `document` with a better default

```js
let document = ref({ contents: [] })
```